# How to overload a method by method with parameters list that contains parameters of the exact same type but parametrized with other types

Tags: java, generics, functional-interface

I have a methods:

```
public List<Integer> convertBy(Function<String, List<String>> flines, Function<List<String>, String> join, Function<String, List<Integer>> collectInts) {
    return collectInts.apply(join.apply(flines.apply((String) value)));
}//first method

public Integer convertBy(Function<List<String>, String> join, Function<String, List<Integer>> collectInts, Function<List<Integer>, Integer> sum) {
    return sum.apply(collectInts.apply(join.apply((List<String>) value)));
}//second method
```

Despite their parameteres are parametrized with different types I cannot overload the first method. I might use different interface, other than `Function<T,R>` but don't know which one would suffice as I went through list of them and couldn't find one https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html.

Parameters in those functions are:

`flines` - reads the file from given path (`String`) and returns list of lines in that file (`List<String>`)

`join` - concatenates element of given `List<String>` and returns a `String`

`collectInts` - parses the given `String` and returns List of integers found in that `String`.

`sum` - adds elements from `List<Integers>` and returns the sum

**Questions:**

1. Can I overload the first mehod by the second one?
2. What other existing functional interface I might use besides function? I think none, as the types of argument and result always differ.

Comment: Due to [type inference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) this is not possible, since at compile-time the types of the lists (or any construct that uses generics, for that matter) are stripped away and that leaves you with two identical function signatures. -- edit: wait, did I understand your question correctly?

Comment: Still deciphering the title of the topic. Please resume it. Anyway the answer at point 1. is no.

Comment: Your abstraction is problematic. When you write a method that accepts a `Function<String,List<String>>` argument, you can't expect that `Function<String,List<String>>` do to something like `reads the file from given path (String) and returns list of lines in that file (List<String>)`, since the caller of your method can pass any `Function` implementation that accepts a `String` and returns a `List<String>` (for example, `s->Arrays.asList(s.split())` will be accepted, even though it doesn't read any files). You should rethink your design.

Comment: Even worse, one of these methods expects `value` to be a `String` while the other assumes it to be a `List<String>`. This can’t work.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create a method which applies multiple functions and is not interested in the intermediate values, you can make it a generic method. The code in your question is strange as it assumes that `value` can be a `String` and a `List<String>` at the same time.

But comparing with [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33298519/2711488), there’s a different picture. While the varargs method there can’t work that way, you can easily provide overloaded methods for the actual use cases:

```
public class InputConverter<T> {

    private T value;

    public InputConverter(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public <R> R convertBy(Function<? super T, ? extends R> f) {
        return f.apply(value);
    }
    public <T1,R> R convertBy(
        Function<? super T, ? extends T1> f1, Function<? super T1, ? extends R> f2) {
        return f2.apply(f1.apply(value));
    }
    public <T1,T2,R> R convertBy(
        Function<? super T, ? extends T1> f1, Function<? super T1, ? extends T2> f2,
        Function<? super T2, ? extends R> f3) {
        return f3.apply(f2.apply(f1.apply(value)));
    }
    public <T1,T2,T3,R> R convertBy(
        Function<? super T, ? extends T1> f1, Function<? super T1, ? extends T2> f2,
        Function<? super T2, ? extends T3> f3, Function<? super T3, ? extends R> f4) {
        return f4.apply(f3.apply(f2.apply(f1.apply(value))));
    }
}
```

Assuming that you fixed your interface types and created functions as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33300743/2711488), you can use it like

```
InputConverter<String> fileConv=new InputConverter<>("LamComFile.txt");
List<String> lines = fileConv.convertBy(flines);
String text = fileConv.convertBy(flines, join);
List<Integer> ints = fileConv.convertBy(flines, join, collectInts);
Integer sumints = fileConv.convertBy(flines, join, collectInts, sum);
```

Comment: It still allows only arbitrary number of arguments (up to 4). Do you think it would be possible to accept more than 4 arguments (that is *any* number of `Function<A,R>` and still have *some* type safety (for example compiler warnings or `ClassCastException` at runtime?

Comment: @REACHUS: sure. You can declare a varargs method using raw types, i.e. `Function... arg`. Then you get compiler warnings when the typed functions are assigned to the raw type parameter. But that’s exactly what [the other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33298519/2711488) is all about. See the declaration right at the beginning of the question… [kocko’s solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33298572/2711488) will work, once the type declaration problems described in my answer have been fixed.

Comment: OK, thanks. I think I'll have to add my own question.